# Unable to get the path of current directory in Android Junit test

Tags: android, junit

I am trying to access my properties and an xls file to setup my framework initially for my test via Android JUnit test.

I have written a class called TestInitialize which does initialization of required stuff for my framework, but the problem which I am facing is, every time I try to get the path of either the properties file or xls file, its not working !!! (And both are there in my current working project directory)

I tried various different options, but nothing is working

Here are options

**Option 1**

```
    String Workspace = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    String fullpath = Workspace + "/Products/Startup.xls";
    String filepath = new File(fullpath).getPath();
```

**Option 2**

```
     String filepath = new File("//Products/Startup.xls").getPath();
```

I have even given the full path (Hardcoded), but still its not working.

For **option 1** and **option 2**, I am getting the result as

```
//Products/Startup.xls
```

Please anyone help on this, since I am baby sitting with this problem for couple of days now !!!

Thanks,
Karthik KK

Answer (score 0):

Actually as I already mentioned in my question, its the restriction in android test project.

To access any of the external resource file, the same has to be done in Android Assets folder (which is located in all the Android test projects folder)

Thus I wrote the following code and its working fine !!!

```
getInstrumentation().getContext().getResources().getAssets().open("Startup.xls");
```

And now its working fine !!!

Thank you all !!

Thanks,
Karthik KK
www.executeautomation.com/blog

Comment: you cann also accept your own answer to show to others that your Question is answered correctly.

Comment: I located my asset file under app/src/androidTest/assets/ folder, but still can not be opened. Where exactly to store my test data files?